# taking ratios of logs in numpy/scipy in Python

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, scipy, logarithm

I'm trying to calculate the ratio of two log values `a` and `b` and then convert it back to non-log values. Since these are log values, the ratio `c` is:

```
from numpy import *
c = a - b
# convert to non-log value
val = exp(c)
```

consider this example:

```
a = -336929.42757
b = -334216.16795
```

since these are log values, the ratio is:

```
c = -2713.259620000026
```

Then I convert the ratio to non-log values and get `0`:

```
val = exp(c)
```

How can I avoid this? What's the correct way to take the ratio of the two logs and convert back to non-log without having this behavior?

Comment: how do you calculate the values you assign to `a` and `b`?

Comment: I do all the arithmetic in log values, so `a` and `b` are just the result of arithmetic on log values. I just take `log(...)` of things and add them/subtract them to end up with two values whose ratio I want to compare

Comment: The final answer is ~4.429e-1179, which is far too small to be stored in a float object.  Is that really the number you want?

Comment: @DSM: no, I just care about the ratio and I want to see if it's greater than a certain cutoff value

Comment: @user248237dfsf you can convert cutoff value into log and compare it with other logs anyway

Comment: Let me try again.  `val == exp(c) == 4.4291364817936896e-1179`.  You can use a `Decimal` instance, or an `mpf` object, or something else, to store it if you really need it, but your ratio won't fit as is in a float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is clearly that exp(-2713.259620000026) not represented well by a float.  But since you know the log of the number, you could do something like:

```
c10 = c/log(10.)
```

so

```
x = 10**c10
```

or, but separating the integer and fractional parts:

```
x = 4.29 x 10^(-1179)
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, the number you're expecting is too small to represent using `float`.
E.g., in my system:

```
In : sys.float_info.min_exp
Out: -1021
```

Therefor, you're getting 0.0

If you only want to compare it to some cutoff value, you can still use the resulting 0.  The "real" unrepresentable number is as good as 0 in your case.